# New bootup menu after partial upgrade

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi

I upgraded both OSs yesterday and have been going through some odd behavior on Ubuntu's end. First the 'Security Boot Fail' screen was popping, so I disabled Secured Boot which solved that issue. However, now when I boot up a *black* screen shows up (formerly purple) and has all these boot options that were never there before:

[image: boot screen]

Here is a copy of the boot-repair pastebin, which i've noticed sda3 is failing to mount.

http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/pDBkBhGX2S/

Last but not least, i'd just like to include an image of my GParted for reference.

[image]

I googled all day yesterday, and I think i'm too novice to understand precisely what the issue is. I appreciate your patience!

Comment: Can you successfully boot Windows and Ubuntu from this grub menu?  If so, I am not sure what you are asking.

Comment: I can ~ i'm curious why sda3 is failing to mount ~ also, why are there so many options on the boot menu now? Used to be only 4 (Ubuntu, Adv Ubuntu Options, Windows Boot Mngr, System Setup).. also used to be purple now it's black?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I suggest rewording your question, including the title, so that it's clear what your situation is, and what you are asking.   People just browsing titles are going to think your system won't boot, and the people with knowledge of your actual issue may not notice your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically the black screen that used to be purple is called Grub. Grub is a bootloader, what a bootloader does is that it holds the entries which you can use to boot up your operating systems.

When grub is installed, the hard disk(s) is scanned for operating systems, then these entries are generated and given to grub.

So what boot repair did was to install grub (not sure what happens to the old grub, maybe it's overwritten). So boot repair scanned your hard disk and generated the entries that you see.

Not entirely sure why boot repair decided to add those extra entries. My guess is that those are .efi files that were found while it was scanning your hard disk (on /dev/sda2) and it just added them. Maybe because its function is to try and help you boot in any possible way it added them. You shouldn't worry anyway. If you want to remove them you can edit `sda6/boot/grub/grub.cfg` and just delete them *(tell me if you need help with that)*.

As for /dev/sda3, this is a "microsoft reserved partition", why do you want to mount it? I have such a partition and I didn't try opening it before. It also gives me that error you see in gparted.

---

You can do `gksu gedit /boot/grub/grub.cfg`. This should have the entries you see when you boot. I saw them in the ubuntu paste that you provided. Take a look at it. The file starts at line 156. and you'll find "menuentry"s at lines like 468, 473... those are the ones that should be removed.

However I didn't do that by hand before so I'm not sure whether you can just delete the entries that you don't like. ...I tried grub-customizer before! you can use it! To install it you can use the ppa method.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
sudo apt update
sudo apt install grub-customizer
```

Comment: This is awesome Mina.. is editing the sda6 grub.cfg different than sudo gedit /etc/default/grub? I’d def like to fix that

Comment: @qorka edited the answer :D

Comment: Bingo.. so, shall I delete 466 - 497 or 468 - 496? I’m assuming I can change the boot color back to purple on line 258 as well? (I have OCD w that stuff =|)

Comment: well like I said you can try but I didn't try it before. I know grub-customizer works fine. It should give you the option to remove the entries, as well as change the background colour. :D I also hated it when the purple colour went away for the first time, but then I got used to it. Now I try many versions of ubuntu and also non-ubuntu linux, so maybe that's the reason.